# WooCommerce Save multiple attribute values on add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I created a foodbowl-creator. http://klanten.visual.be/demoestuin/product/bowl-samenstellen/

I want to save my attributes with multiple values. In the step 'groenten' you can select multiple vegetables. But when I add it to the cart only saves one attribute for a variation. Which is logical.

Can somebody tell me how to save multiple attribute values to the post object when I add this product to the cart?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
I found a working example, but I have no way to contact that person. It is practically the same as I want to make: fingerfoodaffair-shop.ch/product/sandwich. In the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygQnv.jpg) you can see that there are multiple attributes in the string.

That's exactly what I want, how can you save multiple values from an attribute in a string like: attribute1, attribute2, attribute3

Comment: Can you show the areas of code you believe responsible for saving a single attribute?

Comment: Is your product a WC_Product_Variable?

Comment: @Tom : This is what I'm looking for, where can you save the single attribute. So I can change this for multiple.

Comment: @Meganta Cuda : Yes, my product is a variable product.
https://pasteboard.co/26dqvnUBR.jpg

Comment: I have also wanted to do this but I don't think WooCommerce can do this as the attributes in a variation are single valued. The alternatives I thought of was to have the value of the attribute be strings like 'carrots, celery and onions', 'carrots and lettuce', ... In other words the single value of an attribute actually is a combination of values. The other alternative was to have a first vegetable attribute, a second vegetable attribute with an additional none value. None of this is ideal. Maybe someone will give you a better answer and also help me.

Comment: @Magenta Cuda That's exactly what I want... change the multiple attr. to a string, for example : 'Carrots, lettuce' 
I found a suggestion for serializing the $POST object, but no I don't know where to do that

I found a working example, but I have no way to contact that person.
It is practicallythe same as I want to make : 
http://www.fingerfoodaffair-shop.ch/product/sandwich/

In the screen shot you can see that there are multiple attributes in the string : https://pasteboard.co/27oeSt07v.jpg

Comment: I think I may have mislead you. I am actually defining the values of Vegetables in the Attributes pane as carrots, celery and onions | carrots and lettuce | ... where | is used as the separator. Of course this only works if the number of vegetables is small.

Comment: I.e., the combination of vegetables is hard coded as a single value in the Value(s): textarea of the attribute so the options shown to the buyer are a list of combinations from which the buyer selects one. It does not implement a multiple selection of vegetables but allows you to select a combination from a list of combinations. As I said not ideal.

Comment: If the number of vegetables is large then I would define multiple vegetable attributes, e.g., First Vegetable, Second Vegetable, ... These would have the same values and an additional none value. So, in this case the buyer would see multiple select elements for vegetables where each select element chooses one vegetable. Again not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery Get selected Attribute ID, Current Product id , Quantity ETC.
Then send ajax request . where your get ajax request paste this code. your all attribute add into cart . and in ajax responce windows redirect to cart page.

```
global $wpdb;
    global $woocommerce;

    $proid =$_POST['proid'];
    $variationid =$_POST['valpj'];
    $quantity =$_POST['quantity'];
    $arr = array();
    $arr['Photos'] = 'Pics';

    foreach($variationid as $variationid1){
          //echo $variationid1. '<br  />';          
          $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $proid, $quantity, $variationid1, $arr, null ); 

    }
```

Comment: First of all thank you, I'm on the right way.

But I'm not there yet. The product that is added to the card is just a normal product. Not a variable, you can see this in the screenshot.
The first item in my cart is added with your sollution. The second with the standard add to cart button : https://pasteboard.co/2bZYJwkJB.jpg

But it could be that I am still doing something wrong with adding the variations...

Comment: Can you please post your answer @AlexanderDewilde

Comment: @AlexanderDewilde i would like to see your answer as well